# Save state between ajax calls in javasctipt

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, local-storage

I'd like to implement "cache" for retrieved from server data by using `localStorage`. Parameters of request (`requestData`) going to be unique identifier. Here is my code:

```
App = {};
App.Service = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
App.Service.prototype.sendRequest = function(requestData) {
    // process request data somehow and store to local variable
    var identifier = $.param(requestData);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'web/api',
        success: function(data) {
            // can identifier differ from calculated before ajax call?
            // for example if someone else start this method in the same time?
            localStorage.setItem(identifier, data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle error
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: requestData
    });
};
```

And here is my question: suppose I have started the sendRequest method several times. Will each `success` callback method operate on his own `identifier` or they will be mixed (in other words wrong identifiers will be assigned to response data)?

Comment: You no need to worry about messing data betweeen ajax calls, because every sendRequest() call creates its own local 'identifier' variable which ties to success/error callbacks function's closures.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know (I even haven't thought about it) that each function's call creates it's own address space :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered simply creating an array, calling it something like `var cache = []` and just adding the response data to it after each retrieval? Just use some variable to keep track of the last index that you used, or use a date/time if you want to keep track of when the request was made, separate from any response data.

Comment: The idea was to differentiate the items in cache by the request parameter (or the combination of parameters).

Comment: Maybe I described the question not quite clear, but I'm interesting in the behavior of callback functions when they operate on local data. Will they all share one field between each other or operate on the own copy of it?

Comment: The identifier should not change if your function is called as a callback supplied to the `success` property. If you were trying to call the callback manually, you might have had issues with the callback firing before the response is received. Aside from that, the data that was sent is essentially "foreign" when it is returned. By this, I mean that it has nothing to do with anything on your page, and must be extracted from your parsed response as any other data would.

Comment: Does it mean that identifier in success callback function will not reference to identifier in sendRequest method (when success will be invoked)?

Comment: You should be processing the response in the callback,  after you have received the response.